# How to update only first row in SQlite without a sequential int identifier?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I would like to update the first row only. But I don't have a primary key, any sequential identifier.

```
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put(COLUMN_UNAME, c.getUname());
  values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());

  db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,???,???);
```

How to update only first row in SQlite without  a sequential int identifier?

Comment: Do either of the columns represent something that should already be in the table?

Comment: Also, is there ever more than one row in this table?

Comment: @Karakuri No there is only one row

Comment: Have you had a look into `SharedPreferences`? Might work better for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to do so. Every SQLite table has a [`ROWID`](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

> Except for [`WITHOUT ROWID`](http://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) tables, all rows within SQLite tables have a 64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its table. This integer is usually called the "rowid". [...]

So you could just update the row with the smallest `rowid`

```
String where = "rowid=(SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, where, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is only ever one row in the table, you can use `null, null` as the last two arguments, which will update all the rows in the table.

Comment: Thanks @Karakuri , fortunately my table only needs one row and your answer resolved my problem! But I am still curious to know if what I am asking is possible with more than one row. Is it?

Comment: @DatabaseHelper You'd need some way to identify the row. How that would actually be implemented would depend on the data, on how you'd decided to model it.